# Solve system of equations with square roots and fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

$$
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2x+\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)y+1=0\\
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2x+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)y+1=0
\end{cases}
$$

I tried setting the equations equal to each other and substituting variables but those methods just made the equation more conplicated.

Comment: Those radicals are just real numbers.  You have ax + by + 1 = 0; cx + dy + 1 = 0 just solve those as normal.  y = (-1 - cx)/d so ax + b(-1 - cx)/d + 1 = 0 so (a - bc/d)x = -1 + b/d so x = (-1+b/d)/(a-bc/d); y = (-1 - c( (-1+b/d)/(a-bc/d)))/d.

Comment: I edited the original question.  Can you please check that I didn't introduce a typo?  It was easy to make a mistake when reading a rotated paged.

Comment: Setting the equations equal to each other rarely results in something helpful when you have two variables.  The problem is that that doesn't reduce the number of variables.

Comment: You could use for example the fact that $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yes, no typos @Michael Burr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swetting $$a=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ and $$b=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}$$ then we have to solve
$$a^2x+ay=-1$$
$$b^2x+by=-1$$
from the first equation we get
$$y=-\frac{1+a^2x}{a}$$
plugging this in the second equation we get
$$a^2bx-b(1+a^2x)=-1$$ thus
$$x=\frac{b-1}{ab^2-a^2b}$$
can you proceed?